# Stationary distribution for stochastic transition function

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set of points, $F_X$ a $\sigma$-Algebra of its subests. Let $p(x,A)$ be a stochatstic transition function, such that for a fixed $x$, $p(x,A)$ is a probability measure, and for a fixed $A\in F_X$, $p(x,A)$ is measurable.

The transition probabilities in $n$ steps are $p^n(x,A)=\underset{A}{\int} p^{n-1}(\eta ,A)d\eta$.

I want to show that if there exists an integer $k$ such that $\underset{x, \eta ,A}{sup} |p^{(k)}(x,A)- p^{(k)}(y,A)|=\delta<1$, then there exists a probability distribution $P$ such that $|P(A)-p^{(n)}(x,A)|\le \delta^{(n/k)-1}$, and $P(A)=\underset{X}{\int} p(x,A)dx$.

Thanks!

Comment: Your definition for the $n$-step transition probability kernel seems off.

Comment: fixed it, thanks.

Comment: @joeyg : The issue with the n-step transitions remains: Currently, your equation has a left-hand-side that depends on $x$, but the right-hand-side does not.